# How to resolve NameError: name Country is not defined with seaborn.barplot

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I am working of data visualization. I am trying to use `seaborn` library in my python code but each time when ever I try to plot bar chart I get name error for the column that I choose for x and y axis. Please check the attached image for more information:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo. `hue='Country'` not `hue=Country`

Answer (score 1):

You have passed `hue=Country` and it takes it as a variable. Use it like this:

```
sns.barplot(..., hue="Country")
```